# How to save TextField user inputs

Tags: flutter

When the user enter the text on my textfield, how can I use this user input to create an object?

I have class named Item:

```
class Item {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final double price;

  Item(this.id, this.name, this.price);
}
```

I have two textfields, one the name and price. 
I have the following Strings before the build method:

```
String itemInput;
String priceInput;

Item currentItem;
```

In my onChanged method, I save the input to them.

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (String input) => itemInput = input,
)

TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  onChanged: (String price) => priceInput = price,
)
```

How can I create the Item object, once I save the input to the variables?
Currently, the inputs stay uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

use a TextEditing Controller it can save values, after that you can do whatever you want. Just call the .text